# How to make an element fixed in a dropdown based upon the page redirected from?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, forms

Currently have a fully functional form that has a dropdown field that lets the user choose products. I want to ensure the dropdown field is locked to product_x if the user has been redirected to the form from product_page_x (theres a total of 8 products) and the dropdown remains accessible if user has been redirected from any other page except the product pages.

Edit: What I've thought so far is to assign different IDs to the buttons redirecting from each product page and assign null ids to buttons on all pages except product pages and then use js to implement an switch statement that displays a fixed element field according to ID and the defaults to the dropdown. Is this the most optimal approach? I've attached my dropdown and a supposed src page id.

Open to both php and js suggestions. The whole website has been developed using Laravel.
Would appreciate both logical and functional help.

Final edit: Made form redirect buttons return an id (unique to every product page) and then used php to get that id. Used a switch to display simple readonly text field with product name nested inside an if statement that checks if switch var (i.e. id has been set) and then echoed the dropdown in the else block. Open to suggestions about how this could be better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please, add some code, so people can see what have you tried, and then help you.

Comment: What did you attempt ? (show your code)

Comment: Put something in the URL, or maybe Session, to indicate the already-selected product ID. Then manipulate your view using that data so it maybe shows just text instead of a dropdown.

Comment: My apologies, new to posting stuff on Stack, will add an MPE. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

you can use js to select a value and then make the dropdown unclickable.

```
var pageType= "<?php echo ($pageType); ?>" ;
    if (pageType=='product'){
                $("#dropdown").val('product_x');
                $("#dropdown").css("pointer-events","none");
            }
```

It is difficult to give you a proper code without seeing your page design, but this is the basic format on how you can achieve this.$pageType will have to be defined from controller itself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, definitely seems like a better approach than mine. Will share once I implement it successfully.